# Combine 2 Predicted Probabilities graphs in R with SjPlot Package

Tags: r, plot, logistic-regression, sjplot

Lets say I have this code:

```
dt <- data.frame(x = (1:9), z = c(6,5,3,7,8,3,1,6,7), y = c(1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0))
model1 <- glm(y ~ x + z, family = binomial(link = "logit"),
              data = dt)
model2 <- glm(y ~ x + z, family = binomial(link = "logit"),
              data = dt)
summary(model1)
summary(model2)
library(sjPlot)
m <- plot_model(model1, title = "Predicted probabilities", type = "pred", terms = "x")
n <- plot_model(model2, title = "Predicted probabilities", type = "pred", terms = "x")
```

I want to combine both graphs so I can just save them in one file. In both graphs you can find predicted probabilities from the sjPlot Package.

How can I achieve that?

I tried `par(mfrow=c(2,2))` already but it does not work at all.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: do you want to overlay them or just have them side by side in one picture?

Comment: there is a `plot_grid()` function in _sjPlot_. Does this help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tried the `par()` function i assume you want to create the two graphs side by side. You can achieve this with the `grid.arrange()` function of the library `gridExtra` which looks as follows:
[image: gridExtra]

**Used code:**

```
library(sjPlot)
library(gridExtra)

dt <- data.frame(x = (1:9), z = c(6,5,3,7,8,3,1,6,7), y = c(1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0))

model1 <- 0
model2 <- 0

model1 <- glm(y ~ x + z, family = binomial(link = "logit"),
              data = dt)
model2 <- glm(y ~ x^4 + z, family = binomial(link = "logit"),
              data = dt)
summary(model1)
summary(model2)

m <- plot_model(model1, title = "Predicted probabilities", type = "pred", terms = "x")
n <- plot_model(model2, title = "Predicted probabilities", type = "pred", terms = "x")

grid.arrange(m, n, ncol = 1, heights = c(1, 1))
```

If you want them side by side and not one above the other, just change the `ncol` value to 2

Comment: thank you for the fast reply. One more question: How can I add a title like "Logistic". It should not be represented over both plots but just at the head of the combined plot.

Comment: @AmelioTornincasa use the `top="string"` argument. `grid.arrange(m, n, ncol = 1, heights = c(1, 1), top="Logistic")`

Comment: @AmelioTornincasa if you also add the library(grid) you can change the Size of the Title with `top=textGrob("Title", gp=gpar(fontsize=19,font=8))`